# "The image url provided in the request is invalid" when deploying App Runner

Tags: amazon-ecr, amazon-app-runner

I'm deploying an App Runner instance with CloudFormation, and I get the error:

> The image url provided in the request is invalid

The image is set to "public.ecr.aws/z6y3i0f8/template-generator", and I can pull this image with `docker pull public.ecr.aws/z6y3i0f8/template-generator`, so I know the image exists.

I've also set `AutoDeploymentsEnabled` to false, which [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/19762) points out is not supported by public ECR repos.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you must supply the tag, even if using the `latest` image. So the CloudFormation `ImageIdentifier` field needs to be  `public.ecr.aws/z6y3i0f8/template-generator:latest`.